# Join split lines of a string variable when there is no gap between them

Tags: python, string

I have a multi-line string variable (var_text), which look like the following:

```
'I am a
high
school
student

I like
Physics'
```

What i am trying to do is join the split lines that have no gap between them so that the variable looks like the following:

```
'I am a high school student

I like Physics'
```

I have tried to use the following line of code

```
" ".join(var_text.splitlines())
```

but it joins all the lines regardless of the gaps between them, so the end result looks like this:

```
'I am a high school student    I like Physics'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
out = '\n\n'.join([rec.replace('\n', ' ') for rec in s.split('\n\n')])
```

Out:

```
'I am a high school student

I like Physics'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a simple for loop, where you create a new line in your new string when you find an empty line in the original string:

```
s = """'I am a
high
school
student

I like
Physics'"""

r = ""
for line in s.splitlines():
    if line == "":
        r += "\n"
    else:
        r += " " + line
r = r[1:] # Remove the first space
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```python
text = '''I am a
high
school
student

I like
Physics'''

joined = " ".join(text.splitlines())
joined_split = joined.replace("  ", "\n")
print(joined_split)
```

This basically replaces the double space between both lines in your code with a new line. If you wanted to store the 2 variables in a list, you could use this:

```python
text = '''I am a
high
school
student

I like
Physics'''

joined = " ".join(text.splitlines())
joined_split = joined.split("  ")
print(joined_split)
```

This returns a list with each line as a list. A list might be useful later (I have no idea :)

Comment: Hi The Pilot Dude. @Dharman's edit was a good one - conversational and chatty material is generally discouraged here in favour of technical writing.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Got it